# How to transform an adjacency matrix into an incidence Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, graph-theory

I'm trying to transform the adjacency matrix into an incidence matrix of an undirected graph. For edges :
(1, 2), (1,5), (1,6), (2,3), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (5,6)

Adj matrix is  :

0 1 0 0 1 1

1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 1 0

0 0 1 0 1 0

1 1 1 1 0 1

1 0 0 0 1 0

and I expect the result for the incidence matrix to be

0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

but, my program returns this :

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

My source code :

```
 graph constructor
 Graph(int vertices, int edges)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->edges = edges;
        edge = std::vector<Graph::Edge*>(edges);
        for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++)
        {
            edge[i] = new Edge(this);
        }
    }
```

```
  Graph* g = new Graph(numberOfVertices, numberOfEdges);
 g->edge[0]->src = 1;
    g->edge[0]->dest = 2;

    g->edge[1]->src = 1;
    g->edge[1]->dest = 5;

    g->edge[2]->src = 1;
    g->edge[2]->dest = 6;

    g->edge[3]->src = 2;
    g->edge[3]->dest = 3;

    g->edge[4]->src = 2;
    g->edge[4]->dest = 5;

    g->edge[5]->src = 3;
    g->edge[5]->dest = 4;

    g->edge[6]->src = 3;
    g->edge[6]->dest = 5;

    g->edge[7]->src = 4;
    g->edge[7]->dest = 5;

    g->edge[8]->src = 5;
    g->edge[8]->dest = 6;
```

```
 for (i = 0; i < numberOfEdges; i++)
    {
            adjacency_matrix[g->edge[i]->src][g->edge[i]->dest] = 1;
            adjacency_matrix[g->edge[i]->dest][g->edge[i]->src] = 1;

    }

  std::cout << "Adjacency matrix : " << std::endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= numberOfVertices; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<adjacency_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

```
 // Incidence Matrix

    int counter = 0;
    for( int i = 1; i <= numberOfEdges; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numberOfVertices; j++ ){
            if(adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1){
                incidence_matrix[i][counter] = 1;
                incidence_matrix[j][counter] = 1;
                ++counter;
            }

        }
    }
    for( int i = 1; i <= numberOfVertices; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= numberOfEdges; j++){
            std::cout<<incidence_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that the first element in arrays and vectors has index 0, and the last element has index `n - 1` for size `n`? All your loops start with `1` and `<=` in the conditions of `for` loops always look somehow suspicious in C++.

Comment: this is my full code https://replit.com/join/niqwolvbpv-srrrrrrrrrrbu

Comment: @Scheff'sCat if I do this, it no longer displays the right

Comment: @sdblog22 Can yoiu post the code which you used for creating the adjacency marix here,

Comment: @RonaldvanElburg  replit.com/join/niqwolvbpv-srrrrrrrrrrbu you can see the entire program here, it would be difficult to explain only a portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas in the code are correct. But the indexing in the array is wrong.

Indexing should start at 0. Note: this also applies when setting up the adjacency matrix.

The numbers you use to name the vertices/nodes where originally 1,2,3,4,5,6. I propose to call them 0,1,2,3,4,5. Your original edge (1,2) then becomes (0,1). But if we consistently rename all the vertices everywhere we end up with the same graph. The advantage of this new naming convention is that we can use these names directly as indices in the C++ data structures you are using. (Provided we use the corresponding integer value and not consider these names to be strings.)

The specification of the Graph becomes

```
Graph* g = new Graph(numberOfVertices, numberOfEdges);
g->edge[0]->src = 0;
g->edge[0]->dest = 1;

g->edge[1]->src = 0;
g->edge[1]->dest = 4;

g->edge[2]->src = 0;
g->edge[2]->dest = 5;

g->edge[3]->src = 1;
g->edge[3]->dest = 2;

g->edge[4]->src = 1;
g->edge[4]->dest = 4;

g->edge[5]->src = 2;
g->edge[5]->dest = 3;

g->edge[6]->src = 2;
g->edge[6]->dest = 4;

g->edge[7]->src = 3;
g->edge[7]->dest = 4;

g->edge[8]->src = 4;
g->edge[8]->dest = 5;
```

So printing the adjacency matrix becomes:

```
    std::cout << "Adjacency matrix : " << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numberOfVertices; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<adjacency_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

and the calculation of the incidence matrix becomes:

```
// Incidence Matrix

    int counter = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++){  //numberOfVertices!!
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numberOfVertices; j++ ){ 
            if(adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1){
                incidence_matrix[i][counter] = 1;
                incidence_matrix[j][counter] = 1;
                ++counter;
            }

        }
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfEdges; j++){
            std::cout<<incidence_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
```

Note that the order of the edges is determined now by the order in which you traverse the adjacency matrix.

Comment: If when I display the adjacency matrix starting the loop at 0, the adjacency matrix displays incorrectly.

Comment: Even if I start the loop adjacency matrices from 1, and change the code of the incidence Matrix as you wrote it, the result is not the one expected

Comment: As I said the construction of your adjacency matrix probably contains the same error as the code in your post. Also the expected result you give can not be right because for each edge there should be exactly two vertices for which you find a 1 in the incidence matrix.

Comment: You need to renumber the nodes instead of 1 to 6 you should use 0 to 5 in this bit of code:  ```g->edge[0]->src = 1;
    g->edge[0]->dest = 2;

 ...``` Easiest solution is to renumber 6 to 0 and be done with it.

Comment: well, that's what I do, forget I edited the code. Except I have 9 edges, not 6

Comment: The edge numbering is OK. But the node number in this part:``` g->edge[8]->dest = 6; ``` is outside the memory you allocated. Because you allocated 6, but the first node has index 0 and index 6 points at node number 7.

Comment: forgive me, I think I'm too stupid to understand, but I really don't understand what I need to change

Comment: Change: 
g->edge[2]->dest = 6; => g->edge[2]->dest = 0;
g->edge[8]->dest = 6; => g->edge[8]->dest = 0;
Note that the order of the nodes and edges might have changed.

Comment: In your code you are using the numbers as names for the nodes and edges, and at the same time as indices into a C++-datastructures. For you as a human those names are not important, but for C++ the indices make all the difference. As pointed out by @Scheff's cat the need to run from 0 to N-1. With N being the number of objects.

Comment: stop, but why are we doing this? g->edge[8] - >src = 5;
g - >edge[8] - >dect = 6; it means that edge 8 has one end 5 and another end 6, why instead of 6 should 0, i'm very confused

Comment: It is nothing but renaming node 6 to node 0. You were not using node 0 before so it is safe. But it allows you to use the name 0 directly as an index. Alternatively if you want to keep the original order you can renumber all nodes: 1->0,2->1, 3->2,4->3,5->4,6->5.  Then the names also correspond with valid indices.

Comment: @sdblog22 If you understand it now then please accept the answer!

Comment: excuse me if I'm being naughty, but can you rewrite what you want to say in the format in which my graph is described?

Comment: In my vision the notation
g - >edge[0] - >src = 1;
g - >edge[0] - >dest = 2; assumes that edge 0 untested vertex 1 with vertex 2, g - >edge[1] - >src = 1;
g - >edge[1] - > dest = 5; assumes that edge 1 joins Vertex one with Vertex 5 and so on.

Comment: Just for the first edge:
g->edge[0]->src = 0;
g->edge[0]->dest = 1;

Comment: So just lower all dest and src values by 1.

Comment: I think we don't understand each other

Comment: I do what you tell me, I modify the nodes. How can I increment the source and destination? that would mean I have a set of nodes different from the initial ones

Comment: can you please come back with a more detailed answer, so I can mark it as a solution, because now I'm more confused than when I started

Comment: Right. The numbers you use to name the vertices/nodes where originally 1,2,3,4,5,6. I propose to call them 0,1,2,3,4,5. Your original edge (1,2) then becomes (0,1). But if we consistently rename all the vertices everywhere we end up with the same graph. The advantage of this new naming convention is that we can use these names directly as indices in the C++ data structures you are using. (Provided we use the corresponding integer value and not consider these names to be strings.)

Comment: g->edge[0]->src = 0;
    g->edge[0]->dest = 1;

    g->edge[1]->src = 2;
    g->edge[1]->dest = 6;

    g->edge[2]->src = 2;
    g->edge[2]->dest = 7;

    g->edge[3]->src = 3;
    g->edge[3]->dest = 4;

    g->edge[4]->src = 3;
    g->edge[4]->dest = 6;

    g->edge[5]->src = 4;
    g->edge[5]->dest = 5;

    g->edge[6]->src = 4;
    g->edge[6]->dest = 6;

    g->edge[7]->src = 6;
    g->edge[7]->dest = 6;

    g->edge[8]->src = 6;
    g->edge[8]->dest = 7; is that what you meant?

Comment: The correct values are in the answer now. I think. The values 6 and 7 should not appear as src or dest values for this example.

Comment: well I have 9 edges, how should I note them in this case?By the way, for the edges we sent above, the displayed matrices do not correspond to reality, unfortunately

Comment: Your edge indices run from 0 to 8, that is as it should be. No need to change that. It is the vertices that should run from 0 to 5 not 1 to 6.

Comment: God, I can't believe it. This shit) excuse me for expressing) it finally works. I heartily thank you for your help and for wasting your time with me. You're a good man

Comment: @sdblog22 Enjoy!